# Making a full height side Nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a navbar on the left which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z6Cv.png).

To do that I made all of the elements(html, body) 100%. Then I structured it like this

HTML:

```
<div class="span2 leftmenu">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
    <li class="ender"><a></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.leftmenu {
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked {
  border-bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.ender {
  height: 100%;
}

.ender a {
  height: 100%;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the navbar always goes past the bottom of the screen. I want to try and make it stretch jut to wherever the page ends. If I do it at 100% it goes past, and even if i make it something like 60% and it doesn't go to the end it still scrolls past the page. Has anyone made a good working side navbar setup that works with a top navbar as well or does anyone know what I can do to fix what i have?

Comment: By the way, the ender class element is not necessary, if it has no content, it shouldn't be there. You can just add `padding-bottom` to the `.nav` class if you need extra space on the bottom.

Comment: Well I also wanted to have the line as well like in the picture. And how would I make the padding only go to the bottom of the screen and not farther?

Comment: well it depends on what browsers you are targeting, using jquery to dynamically redefine the padding every time the height is resized is probably the most versatile though. Which line are you referring to in the picture?

Comment: I am going for something along the lines of a side menu like here http://beer2code.com/themes/core-admin/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html

Comment: Which line are you trying to mimic?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should show more html and css so that we can see more clearly what the issue is. However, height 100% doesn't take into account the border and padding of the parent elements. Try zero-ing these out for the body, and any other ascendant element of your navbar:

```
body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}
```

There are other approaches though, such as enclosing your main content and the navbar in a wrapper element - make the wrapper stretch to the full height, give the navbar a transparent background so that the background of the wrapper-element shows through; or look-into *faux-columns*. [alistapart](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns)

Comment: Stretching the wrapper only works if you have the body set to a specific height, because only the `HTML` element will start with a specific height of 100% if nothing is specified. So you would need to specify the height of the parent of the `.nav` menu, which isn't bad, just letting you know.

Comment: @IlanBiala I don't quite follow. Yes, you can set a specific height of the parent element, but you can also use 100% height (if desirable) by setting this on the wrapper, but also on the body (and any descendant elements in-between). But maybe I've misunderstood you. Andy.

Comment: To have `height: 100%;` work for any element, it's parent element needs to have a defined height...the only element that has an implied height is the `html` element which has its height defined as 100%, so the `body`'s height needs to be defined as do any other elements' heights that are parents of the `.nav` for the `.nav`'s `height: 100%;` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the height set on .ender and .endar a. They are forcing the height of your navbar to be greater than the window height. If you need .ender for a styling reason (e.g. it is containing some kind of background) then I would position it absolutely within the navbar, and not within the list.

So, remove:

```
.ender {
height: 100%;
}

.ender a {
height: 100%;
}
```

I would also remove the margin automatically set on the body tag.

**Here is the code: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMGFs/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to tell exactly what the problem is without more information, but it seems like removing `height:100%` from all the elements you've listed except for `.leftmenu`, adding 100% to the `html` and `body`, and applying a reset would work.

ie:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
}

.leftmenu {
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well even with that, the issue I have is that I want either that last element in the list, to either stretch to the bottom, or I want another similar box thing like in this photo http://i.imgur.com/7XO8CX5.png stretching to the bottom so the full side is cut off.

Comment: what about just removing the `.ender` altogether and making `.leftmenu`s background the same color as the body bg? fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mzmm/8NKC4/

Answer (score 0):

You might find this article interesting:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

In order for a div to be 100%, it's parents also need to be 100% in height.

Therefore, the other examples of

```
html, body, span2 {
   height:100%;
}
```

are correct.

Comment: Well even with that, the issue I have is that I want either that last element in the list, to either stretch to the bottom, or I want another similar box thing like in this photo http://i.imgur.com/7XO8CX5.png stretching to the bottom so the full side is cut off.

Comment: I said that before you even answered this question in Andy G's comment, next time, please read before you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for..?

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.leftmenu {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  float: left;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked {
  border-bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.ender {
  height: 100%;
}

.ender a {
  height: 100%;
}

.right-side {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="span2 leftmenu">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
    <li class="ender"><a></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="right-side">
  right content
</div>
```